# Prevent Windows 8 from automatically opening the mail app on logon

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Every time I logon to windows 8.1, it opens the annoying mail app automatically, and I have to close it each time. How would I go about preventing it from opening?

I already tried logging out of mail. Didn't work.

Comment: have your tried to run msconfig and disable it at startup? Check application settings if it can be disabled during startup too.

Comment: There's no listing for it in the startup applications. Application settings dont show any option either.